# Trying to add an Array Column to existing Postgres table

Tags: postgresql

Why doesn't this command work?

```
ALTER TABLE candidate ADD COLUMN blocked_companies ARRAY;
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: syntax error at or near "ARRAY"

Comment: I would appreciate if people would explain why a question receives a negative point. Would help future participation.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to specify a datatype. If you want an array of strings, use text:

```
ALTER TABLE candidate ADD COLUMN blocked_companies text[];
```

if you want an array of numbers, use int:

```
ALTER TABLE candidate ADD COLUMN blocked_companies int[];
```

More details can be found in the manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION

But in most cases using arrays is not such a good idea (despite Postgres' awesome array support). A properly normalized model might work better for your.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, I'll give it a shot. Why are using arrays not a good idea?

Comment: @SurajKapoor: because multiple values in a single column violate the normalization principle.